# Torch: backpropagate gradients without updating variables

Tags: pytorch, gradient, torch, backpropagation

In pytorch, is there an efficient way to back propagate the gradients but not update their corresponding variables? It seems making a copy of the weights every time during update is too expensive. But `no_grad` & `set_grad_enabled` does not allow back propagation.

Ex. The following seems to take too much time, as it needs to do a copy of the model every time weights are updated:

```
    def __init__():
        …
        self.model = MyModel()
        self.func1 = FuncModel1()
        self.func2 = FuncModel2()
        …
    def trainstep(input):
        f1 = self.func1(input)
        f2 = self.func2(input)
        …
        # want to update weights in model & f1 with respect to loss1
        loss1 = my_loss(model(f1), y1) 

        # don’t want to update weights in self.model with respect to loss2
        # but want to update weights in f2 for loss2
        copy_model = MyModel()
        copy_model.load_state_dict(self.model.state_dict())
        loss2 = my_loss(copy_model(f2), y2) 

        total_loss = loss1 + loss2
        …

        total_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: What are f1 and f2? Please show your full model definition

Comment: This is not real code: I'm giving an example. f1 & f2 are tensors computed using weights I want to update.

Answer (score 0):

when `loss.backward()` pytorch propagates gradients through the entire compute graph.
However, `backward()` function itself does not update any of the weights, it only computes gradients.
The update is done via the optimizer in `optimizer.step()`. If you want to exclude the weights of `f1` and `f2` from the updates, you can simply either
- init `optimizer` without the parameters of `f1` and `f2`.
- set the learning rate for `f1` and `f2` to zero.

Comment: What if I want to update the weights in “model” with respect to loss1, but do not want to update them with respect to loss2? Also I want to update the weights in f1 & f2 with respect to the losses

Comment: @ssssay then you'll have to do some juggling with the optimizer, the parameters and the backprop. You have the different means: `require_grad`, `no_grad` and the parameters in the optimizer.Use these tools wisely.